# make whole layout scrollable if it contains childlayout inside

Tags: android

I want to make my view scrollable, my view contains childs layouts inside linear layout.

My code is below; please make it scrollable, so that every content can be shown ...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#1A77BD">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:id="@+id/version"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TYPE"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_width="200dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update_me"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DATE"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accsetting"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="COUNTRY" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_width="200dip" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/savecorp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="STATE" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_width="200dip" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="102dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/saveuserid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CITY" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_marginTop="95dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_width="200dip" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="152dip"
            android:id="@+id/savepassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VENDOR"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_width="200dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accsetting"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AMOUNT:" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dip"
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accsetting"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:text="NOTES:" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_width="200dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/attachreciepts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Attach Receipts" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/attachreciepts"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:text="Attach Receipts" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just add scroll view as ur parent layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap everything in a

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
*your code*
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without trying your layout I'd suggest changing the top LinearLayout to have a android:layout_height="wrap_content" for starters.